# Invalid LngLat object: (NaN, NaN) in react js , "Mapbox"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, mapbox, react-props

**The project concept is to get geolocation and showing Mapbox map using API...**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { geolocated } from "react-geolocated";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import fetchFakeData from "./api/fetchFakeData";
import Popup from "./components/Popup";
import "./App.css";

mapboxgl.accessToken ="pk.eyJ1IjoiamFja3Nvbi1rYXNpIiwiYSI6ImNrbzdsaDJvNTFvc3Eycm9pdTRxYmRxZjUifQ.BzA0w0U7lP0Ka3FcKkI_1Q";

const App = (props) => {
const mapContainerRef = useRef(null);
const popUpRef = useRef(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 15 }));
```

// initialize map when component mounts

```
useEffect(() => {
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: mapContainerRef.current,
  // See style options here: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#styles
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
  center: [props.lat, props.long],
  zoom: 12.5
});
```

// add navigation control (zoom buttons)

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), "bottom-right");

map.on("load", () => {
  // add the data source for new a feature collection with no features
  map.addSource("random-points-data", {
    type: "geojson",
    data: {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: []
    }
  });
```

// now add the layer, and reference the data source above by name

```
  map.addLayer({
    id: "random-points-layer",
    source: "random-points-data",
    type: "symbol",
    layout: {
      // full list of icons here: https://labs.mapbox.com/maki-icons
      "icon-image": "bakery-15", // this will put little croissants on our map
      "icon-padding": 0,
      "icon-allow-overlap": true
    }
  });
});

map.on("moveend", async () => {
  // get new center coordinates
  const { lng, lat } = map.getCenter();
  // fetch new data
  const results = await fetchFakeData({ longitude: lng, latitude: lat });
  // update "random-points-data" source with new data
  // all layers that consume the "random-points-data" data source will be updated automatically
  map.getSource("random-points-data").setData(results);
});

// change cursor to pointer when user hovers over a clickable feature
map.on("mouseenter", "random-points-layer", (e) => {
  if (e.features.length) {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = "pointer";
  }
});

// reset cursor to default when user is no longer hovering over a clickable feature
map.on("mouseleave", "random-points-layer", () => {
  map.getCanvas().style.cursor = "";
});

// add popup when user clicks a point
map.on("click", "random-points-layer", (e) => {
  if (e.features.length) {
    const feature = e.features[0];
    // create popup node
    const popupNode = document.createElement("div");
    ReactDOM.render(<Popup feature={feature} />, popupNode);
    // set popup on map
    popUpRef.current
      .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
      .setDOMContent(popupNode)
      .addTo(map);
  }
});

// clean up on unmount
return () => map.remove();
}, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

return <div className="map-container" ref={mapContainerRef} /> 
};

export default geolocated({
positionOptions: {
enableHighAccuracy: false
},
userDecisionTimeout: 5000
})(App);

class Gps extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();

this.state = {
  latitude: "",
  longitude: ""
};

this.getMyLocation = this.getMyLocation.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
this.getMyLocation();
}

getMyLocation() {
const location = window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation;

if (location) {
  location.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      this.setState({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      });
    },
    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        latitude: "err-latitude",
        longitude: "err-longitude"
      });
    }
  );
}}

render() {
const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;

return (
  <div>
    <App lat={latitude} long={longitude} />
  </div>
);
}
}
```

**please see this link "codesandbox" : https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-river-7dt0h?file=/src/App.js**

**props didn't work.**

**see this lines:**

1. center: [props.lat, props.long]
2. <App lat={latitude} long={longitude}  / >

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3cWJ.png)

Comment: Hey @Art, did the answer I shared help you?

Answer (score 1):

#### The Problem

The `Lat` and `Lng` were initialized to an empty string, but the `center` property is expecting an array of numbers.

#### Solution

In `Gps` component, initialize the `lat` and `long` state values to a number as opposed to an empty string

```js
this.state = {
  latitude: 38.8951,
  longitude: -77.0364
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was using it for web and the issue was causing because of the height of the div in which I was rendering `map` component. When I set the `minHeight` for that div, it worked fine for me.